# Basic Query on JAXRS and tomee

Tags: json, rest, tomcat, jax-rs

My understanding regarding TomEE (or any Java EE 6 container) is all that i just need to deploy a JAX-RS based application with correct service class annotated.

```
@Path("/hr")
public class HelloRest {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getClichedMessage() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

The TomEE container SHOULD take care of converting the "hello world" to proper json format {"hello world"}

I was wondering why TomEE is not converting it to JSON format. Please note I've not used any spring configuration for CXF as I expect this to work with/without CXF configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certified Web Profile implementation of TomEE does not implement JAX-RS, since JAX-RS is not part of the Web Profile in Java EE 6 (it is in Java EE 7 though).

However, since it appeared that there actually IS very useful stuff in Java EE 6 that goes beyond the Web Profile, TomEE has 2 extra distributions that contains some of this extra stuff.

On the [download page](http://tomee.apache.org/downloads.html) you'll find the "JAX-RS" and "Plus" distributions that both contain JAX-RS. With those (or any full profile Java EE AS) you indeed don't need any configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Produces/Consumes doesnt mean convert, it is mainly http headers. String in json is a...string. depend of course of your body writer.